# How to translate “Me doing X” like in online posts?

Tags: langage-informel, langage-des-jeunes

How do you say something like “me avoiding my problems” or “me watching TV” like in memes or stuff like that?

Answer (score 15):

In the context of memes, you will say something like "quand j'évite les problèmes". Here, the adverb "quand" highlights the same idea of an action as the BE-ing present.

Here is an example:

> [image: Example of a meme, The Office]
>
> "Quand j'apprends que la fête est annulée"

Comment: Definitely the correct answer when it comes to memes

Comment: *"Quand j'apprends que la fête est annulée"* would be translated to *When I learn that the party is canceled*. This is basically the same idea than the MRW ("My Reaction When"/"Ma réaction quand") meme.

Comment: And it was the question in fact ;) but in French memes we don't really say "Ma réaction quand" but only "Quand..."

Answer (score 3):

If you're also using this form instead of the longer "that's me doing X" while showing pictures to friends and relatives you'll find that the following forms are very often used; you can also use these forms in various ways as for instance in a humourous way or a sarcastic fashion when you draw a comparison between yourself and a personnage (real life character or played character) or entity of any sort (Mickey Mouse, a monkey, a martian, …) that you see in a paper, on TV, on film in general, in a painting, or even as a statue.

- Moi en train de X     Moi en train de lire le journal
- Moi à X    à la batterie, à la vaisselle, … (*"à la vaisselle" might be at the limit of what is acceptable. (see commments)*)
- Moi devant X    Moi devant le café de la gare, …
- Moi sur …, sous …, … (*There is no end of the prépositions and forms you can use here.*)

You can replace "Moi" with "**C'est moi**" or "**Me voilà**"; if you want to make a transition from one picture to the next, you can add "**Là c'est**" or "Ça c'est" in front of "Moi" (Là c'est moi …).

In most 
of these forms and contexts you can change "moi "with "toi", "vous", "lui", "elle" and "eux", and thus, instead of pointing at yourself, make someone else the subject of your remark.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94456/discussion-on-answer-by-lph-how-to-translate-me-doing-x-like-in-online-posts).